# Creating an iPhone like roller in Android using ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-controls

I want to create a better `NumberPicker` then the one used in `DatePicker`. I looked at the **HTC Sense** Alarm clock Roller (looks like the `iPhone` Spinner/Roller), I want to create something like that.

I've created a `ListView` that looks right, but I need a way to get the current id of the middle row. `ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` kind of does what I want but it will give me +-1 errors. Another problem is that the scrolling should lock into a certain row when "dying" out. These are of course related and I hope I can solve this by using a custom `ListView`, but it's hid in the API.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

May be you can use this project on google code

https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

I did not tried it but seems that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to replace those three ListView cells with ViewFlipper objects. As with their help you might be able to flip in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to force ListView to behave as a kind of widget it is not seems like a bad approach.  How about writing the widget yourself?  If I was going to sit down and write such a thing in the platform, I definitely wouldn't try to build it on list view, nor probably any other widget.  It makes sense as its own kind of thing.